# How to send selected value from jquery to controller in Spring MVC

Tags: jquery, jsp, spring-mvc

I am using jquery in my jsp page.My requirement is that on selection of dropdown, my control should pass to the controller.

This worked fine with jquery but I am unable to retrieve the selected value in the controller.

Jsp:

```
select name="Release" id="ReleaseId" class="target">
    <c:forEach var="lineRelase" items="${listOfFeaturesToShow}">
        <option><c:out value="${lineRelase}" /></option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
 <select name="EnvType" id="EnvTypeId" class="target">
    <c:forEach var="lineenvType" items="${listOfFeaturesToShow}">
        <option><c:out value="${lineenvType}" /></option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
<select name="InstallType" id="InstallTypeId" class="target">
    <c:forEach var="lineInstallType" items="${listOfFeaturesToShow}">
        <option><c:out value="${lineInstallType}" /></option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>

$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".target").change(function() {
            check();
        })
    });

    function check() {
        var ReleaseId = $("#ReleaseId").val();
        var EnvTypeId = $("#EnvTypeId").val();
        var InstallTypeId = $("#InstallTypeId").val();
        if (ReleaseId != null && ReleaseId != '' && EnvTypeId != null
                && EnvTypeId != '' && InstallTypeId != null
                && InstallTypeId != '') {
            document.location.href = 'http://localhost:8080/Spring3MVC/foo';
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void abc(HttpServletRequest request){
    System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
    System.out.println("value of install="+ request.getParameter("InstallType"));
```

}

value of install is coming to be null.Kindly help.I am new to jquery. I need the selected value of InstallType,EnvType and Release in my controller.

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
document.location.href = 'http://localhost:8080/Spring3MVC/foo';
```

to this:

```
document.location.href = 'http://localhost:8080/Spring3MVC/foo?ReleaseId='
                                               + ReleaseId 
                                               +'&EnvTypeId' + EnvTypeId 
                                               +'&InstallTypeId'+InstallTypeId;
```

---

Issue seems to me that you are not sending the values in the url as you are using method `GET` then you url should contain the vars you want to have on your server side.

Comment: By doing this, I am only able to get value of first parameter i.e. ReleaseId

Values of  EnvTypeId  and InstallTypeId is still null.I tried using & for e.g. '&EnvTypeId' + EnvTypeId but didn't work..

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

your url with *ReleaseId*, *EnvTypeId* and *InstallTypeId* parameters should look like:

```
document.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/Spring3MVC/foo?
                                   ReleaseId="+ReleaseId+
                                   "&EnvTypeId="+EnvTypeId+
                                   "&InstallTypeId="+InstallTypeId;
```